# Migrate Data to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rackspace-cloud, rackspace-cloudfiles

I need to migrate large data from Rackspace CloudFiles to Amazon S3.Can anyone help me how do I do this? What is the best and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Both Cloud Files (http://docs.rackspace.com/) and S3 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html) have APIs and plenty of SDKs. Your best bet is to write something.

You could alternatively try to find some fuse libraries to allow you to do a straight filesystem copy, but that likely wouldn't be very efficient, especially if you have large file systems.